# combinations with ajacent numbers

Tags: binary, combinations, combinatorics

Consider a binary string of length k, which has exactly m zeros (and, consequently, the remaining k-m elements are "1"). What is the total number of such strings that have exactly j transitions from element zero to element one? (j could be any number between 1 and 2m). 
For example, if k=5, m=2 and j=1 then there are only two such strings: 11100 and 00111.
When k=5, m=2 and j=3 then there are four such strings: 10110, 01011, 11010 and 01101.
When k=5, m=2 and j=4 then there is only one such string: 10101.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
#Example 1
k <- 5
m <- 2
j <- 1

y <- expand.grid(rep(list(0L:1L), k))
zeros <- apply(y,1,function(x) sum(x == 0))
chg <- apply(y,1,function(x) sum(diff(sign(x)) != 0))

y[zeros==m&chg==j,]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
8     1    1    1    0    0
29    0    0    1    1    1

#Example 2
k <- 5
m <- 2
j <- 3

y <- expand.grid(rep(list(0L:1L), k))
zeros <- apply(y,1,function(x) sum(x == 0))
chg <- apply(y,1,function(x) sum(diff(sign(x)) != 0))

y[zeros==m&chg==j,]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
12    1    1    0    1    0
14    1    0    1    1    0
23    0    1    1    0    1
27    0    1    0    1    1

#Example 3
k <- 5
m <- 2
j <- 4

y <- expand.grid(rep(list(0L:1L), k))
zeros <- apply(y,1,function(x) sum(x == 0))
chg <- apply(y,1,function(x) sum(diff(sign(x)) != 0))

y[zeros==m&chg==j,]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
22    1    0    1    0    1
```